# Web Bluetooth API Error: No Services matching UUID

Tags: javascript, browser, bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt, web-bluetooth

I'm playing with the [Web Bluetooth API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API) and I'm trying to get the current battery level of my device (Xiaomi MyBand, BLE device) from the browser.
I'm a little bit newbie with the bluetooth web api, keep in mind maybe I'm missing something basic.

My setup:

- Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 (64 bits)
- macOS Mojave v10.14

This is my Javascript code, I call this function when I click a button:

```
  navigator.bluetooth
    .requestDevice({filters: [
        { name: 'MI' }, 
        { services: ['battery_service'] }
    ]})
    .then(device => {
      console.log(1)
      return device.gatt.connect()
    })
    .then(server => {
      console.log(2)
      return server.getPrimaryService('battery_service')
    })
    .then(service => {
      console.log(3)
      return service.getCharacteristic('battery_level')
    })
    .then(characteristic => {
      console.log(4)
      return characteristic.readValue()
    })
    .then(value => {
      console.log(5)
      console.log(value.getUint8(0))
    })
    .catch(error => { 
       console.log('error: ', error) 
    })
```

I log number *2* and then I get this error:
[image: Chrome console]

> Error: NotFoundError: No Services matching UUID 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb found in Device.

I'm stuck. Any idea about what I need to do?

**Full example code** is here: https://github.com/baumannzone/browser-apis/blob/master/src/views/Bluetooth/Example1.vue

**Live Demo**: https://browser-apis.netlify.com/#/bluetooth

Thanks you all.

Comment: Is the service there?  Confirm with a tool such as chrome://bluetooth-internals or nRF Connect.  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web#dev_tips

Comment: Also, try this generic battery level reading sample, known to work with other devices: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/battery-level-async-await.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Yes, it's listed in chrome BT internals, see: https://i.imgur.com/l4YGHSR.png. I just want to get some device information, I don't need specifically battery. I just want to demonstrate I can read something of the device from the browser (not only the name)

Comment: I do not see the service ...180f... in that screen shot.  You have expanded service ...fee0... (registered assigned number, found in https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/16-bit-uuids-for-members/ ) .  Again, the device likely isn't exposing that service (even if it advertises it).  Try reading other service/characteristics it does expose. A search finds some info at https://github.com/nikita-graf/mi-band-1s-web-bluetooth which may help.